# how do I parse JSON in action script?

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I want to parse the JSON

```
[ 
{ 
    "food": [ 
        { 
            "name": "pasta", 
            "price": 14.50, 
            "quantity": 20 
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "soup", 
            "price": 6.50, 
            "quantity": 4 
        } 
    ] 
}, 
{ 
    "food": [ 
        { 
            "name": "salad", 
            "price": 2.50, 
            "quantity": 3 
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "pizza", 
            "price": 4.50, 
            "quantity": 2 
        } 
    ] 
} 
]
```

How can I get elements from the JSON like each array and element from each array. I have more bigger JSON than this. Line by line parsing of which takes several minutes. Any solution to do it faster.
Expecting link of org JSON util or such and some code for how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) is a library that includes a JSON static class that has a function `JSON.parse()`. This should be already included in your flash project by default.

`JSON.parse()` takes a String and returns your parsed JSON object. If you need assistance interpreting/accessing the results, there are numerous tutorials for using JSON.parse() on the internet.

Comment: If targeting flash player 11 and up as3corelib is no longer required as flash has native json parsing. Can just do JSON.parse() to get the object or JSON.stringfy() to turn an object into a json string.